# Запись в TSV файл

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Я пытаюсь записать в tsv файл значения функции из Python:

```
array([2.8486006e-01, 4.0123294e-01, 2.3942324e-01, 4.9148569e-01,
      ....2.3848413e-01, 8.7266402e-01, 3.0165096e-01, 3.2174571e-01])
```

Записать нужно так, чтобы в каждой строке было по одному значению функции и 8 значащих цифр после запятой.
Мой код:

```
A_reshape = A.reshape(-1, 1)
with open("ans.tsv", "w") as my:
    my.write(str(A_reshape))
```

Получается:

```
[[2.8486006e-01]
 [4.0123294e-01]
 [2.3942324e-01]
 [4.9148569e-01]
 ...
```

Как избавится от скобок и записать в правильном виде?

Comment: Я использую Python и библиотеку NumPy

Comment: Добавляйте это метками, а не в текст вопроса ;-)

Comment: `np.savetxt('ans.tsv', A_reshape, delimiter='\t', fmt='%.8f')`